# MS Access Subform HWnd Reference

Tags: ms-access, vba

Iam building a basic database for a friend oriented to have a simple and intuitive GUI.
For this purpose I have a main form with a Tab control in which each page has two subform controls.
In the first subform a single form with buttons is loaded to serve as a sidebar while in the second subform loads a requested continuous form or report.
I have noticed that when I load a report to the second subform and apply a filter to it I cannot reference functions that reside within the single form that serves as a sidebar.
This is reflected also to a textbox control on the sidebar included for search purposes that loses its value in the time the filter is applied.
What I have managed to track down is that when the filter is applied to the subreport the subform control with the sidebar Hwnd property changes.

Any ideas why this happens ?

Comment: Please provide more information and clarity. Please see [Ask]. Please provide the code that is having the problem, indicate which line of code is getting an error, and include the error number and full description.  The hWnd of a Form or Report will not change unless it is closed and reopened.  More details please and we might be able to help you.

Comment: Have you used the inbuilt navigation controls to build your form? If so they silently "unload" any pages not being displayed, so you would lose your form references.

Comment: I know that the description may not entire help. I cant provide a code example right now but I replicated the  problem. I built a single form with just two child controls that loads a "sidebar" form and a subreport. When I apply a filter to the subreport both child contols reload an new instance of themselves with a new Hwnd. I assume that this is native acces behavior. Thus I dont understand why it reloads all child controls instead of only the one the filter is applied. I just used an another approach with queries instead of applying filters to get rid of this behavior.